# Attempted to fix androids "ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class" went bad

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

After trying to fix this on my own from what I have seen around the net I cannot still figure out what this means:

```
[2013-08-15 23:58:27 - StudioTab] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2013-08-15 23:58:27 - StudioTab] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-08-15 23:58:27 - StudioTab] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I have no idea what this is really telling me or where to start look.  Am I recursively including a library somehow?  My build path under order and export are as thus:

```
Google APIs [Android 3.0]
Android Dependencies
   annotations.jar
Android Private Libraries
    A ton of jars for various functionality i need: CSV writing, talking to the           google calendar somehow...etc...etc.  They are jars I found on the net, not ripped from another project but found to solve problems i.e. how to access google calendar from the device and read/write to it etc...  is this where my problem lies? I can provide a complete list of the jars I am using here.
android-support-v4.jar
```

I added that one as an external jar myself.  I forget what it needs it for but if I remove it it cannot use somethings weird stuff like FragmentActivity and that.

So where do I even begin to look so I can pick this project back up again...get it compiling and running on an emulator.

LIBS folder is as thus:
         Volume in drive D is LargeWorkDisk
         Volume Serial Number is 206C-D951

```
     Directory of D:\Programming\StudioTab\libs

    08/16/2013  12:39 AM    <DIR>          .
    08/16/2013  12:39 AM    <DIR>          ..
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM         1,700,072 android-1.5_r4-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM         2,136,034 android-1.5_r4.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            55,191 commons-codec-1.3-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            46,725 commons-codec-1.3.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            74,976 commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            60,686 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            53,983 google-api-client-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            44,653 google-api-client-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            13,356 google-api-client-extensions-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            15,276 google-api-client-extensions-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             3,459 google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             4,556 google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           309,295 google-collections-1.0-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           639,592 google-collections-1.0.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           188,771 google-http-client-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           196,915 google-http-client-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             6,433 google-http-client-extensions-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             7,807 google-http-client-extensions-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             3,021 google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             3,854 google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM             6,638 google-http-client-extensions-android3-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            10,418 google-http-client-extensions-android3-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            35,765 google-oauth-client-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            34,394 google-oauth-client-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            38,030 google-oauth-client-extensions-1.5.0-beta-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            48,289 google-oauth-client-extensions-1.5.0-beta.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           140,057 gson-1.6-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           164,984 gson-1.6.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           640,031 guava-r09-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM         1,143,921 guava-r09.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           390,195 httpclient-4.0.3-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           292,893 httpclient-4.0.3.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           291,844 httpcore-4.0.1-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           172,888 httpcore-4.0.1.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           200,880 jackson-core-asl-1.6.7-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           201,086 jackson-core-asl-1.6.7.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           283,945 jdo2-api-2.3-eb-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           192,820 jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           476,722 joda-time-1.6-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           534,827 joda-time-1.6.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            39,665 jsontoken-1.0-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            37,877 jsontoken-1.0.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            33,015 jsr305-1.3.9.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           147,086 junit-4.8.2-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           237,344 junit-4.8.2.jar
    08/16/2013  12:39 AM                 0 libsdir.txt
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            11,358 LICENSE
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            14,146 opencsv-2.3.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            12,986 opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            18,492 opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           125,968 ormlite-android-4.24-javadoc.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            22,285 ormlite-android-4.24-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            32,707 ormlite-android-4.24.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           216,486 ormlite-core-4.24.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           140,718 protobuf-java-2.2.0-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           320,306 protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM               501 readme.html
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           158,114 servlet-api-2.5-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           105,112 servlet-api-2.5.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            25,014 transaction-api-1.1-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM            15,071 transaction-api-1.1.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           124,724 xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           128,334 xpp3-1.1.4c-sources.jar
    08/15/2013  09:45 PM           120,069 xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
                  64 File(s)     12,952,660 bytes
                   2 Dir(s)  2,057,125,945,344 bytes free
```

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about your own application - things like "I forget what it needs it for" and "somethings weird" aren't encouraging. The error message is *very* clear about the problematic class (`javax.xml.namespace.QName`) so you should find out which jar file is including that.

Comment: it has been a while, mostly what I am saying is why did it work before and not now...I haven't changed the api level im building against, It must be that I created this on eclipse with the adt installed and the sdk installed seperately and not all as one package.

Comment: Well presumably you changed something, but we don't know what you've done. Anyway, I've explained what you should do to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Same problem and nothing to do. whatsoever, with that javax jar. Somehow the build is pulling that in but nothing i'm using does. Lots of people seem to have come across this building android apps and it seems the most common problem is a misconfigured IDE adding in android.jar multiple times. Since I'm building with gradle it's certainly not that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dalvik JVM does not support the entire API of Oracle JDK. I think `javax.*` packages aren't available to Android. For example there's no `AWT` or `Swing` or `Graphics2D` of Java on Android.

From the error, it looks like you app is using this Class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html

This shouldn't happen If you set up your IDE to use Android SDK instead of JDK.

Comment: I wonder where that is coming from, it is probably the ormlite jars i was using for the ormlite-android-4.24.jar.  If i had to guess...and as the above poster suggested it tells me where that is.  QName... I am not sure how to search inside jars, I don't think windows search does it I wonder if eclipses does.

Comment: @Codejoy No, `ORMLite` is for android. What other libraries are you using ? Can you do a search for `javax.xml` in source files ?

Comment: Let me edit my post.  Also I must admit I am not using those packages that I know of myself let me run it down.  Two things though, you said I should set my IDE to use the Android SDK, it is as far as i can tell, it is set to use java 1.7 with the installed jre7 ?

Comment: @Codejoy I don't know about eclipse, but intellij and android studio do have a "project sdk" setting for that, and android is an option apart from jdk's.

Comment: @Codejoy It should be in one of the xml libraries, most likely `xmlParserAPIs`.

Comment: k trying to remove it, its in some sort of container eclipse is freaking out about.

Comment: I think I had a ton of jars that shouldnt be in there and I need to clean it up.  Thanks for the help...if the "ton of jars" sounds like the culprit then I might be on the right track.

Comment: @Codejoy can you Please tell where is the "project sdk" setting in Android Studio? In which menu?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Maven to build then make sure that your dependency on the android SDK has scope of `provided`, otherwise you will get this message as DEX tries to include all the classes in the android.jar.

Ie

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2_r3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have the gradle equivalent for this?

Comment: No, sorry. I have tried to use the mess that is gradle, but I like my builds repdocible.

Comment: I don't agree with that statement and have found our builds very reproducible, but to each its own. I would recommend giving it a second spin once it leaves beta state (!) because it really blows ANT out of the water, and is a superset of Maven.

Comment: I ditched Ant for Maven 7 years ago and have never used Ant to build Android projects. I beg to differ on Gradle being a superset of Maven, it seems to be the other way around. Gradle appears to be where Maven was back in 2004, just starting to understand the space. IMHO it has a long long way to go.

Comment: Superset in the sense that you can execute maven plugins and create gradle tasks on top. But yes, we agree there's still a way to go.

Comment: Maven can execute Gradle tasks too https://github.com/if6was9/gradle-maven-plugin.

Comment: Even if this is very old gradle has the support of provided dependencies. you can write it as the *`compile`* dependencies just use the keyword *`provided`*. Example: `provided 'com.example:lib:1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by choosing an alternative set of the dependencies while migrating a project from Eclipse to Android Studio. Initially I used springframework.web and javax.xml.transform to make my code pass the build. But the app aborted immediately at runtime with "Ill-advised" error. Then I replaced those two dependencies with 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE', 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13' and 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'. The problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since some users asked about gradle:
In Android Studio, you might be referencing a library from within gradle build, like thus (let us say `javax.annotation`):

```
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

remove (comment out) this call from your dependencies.

[download jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxannotationjar.htm), include in `libs` folder and right click to `Add as library`.  You should be right as rain.

Answer (score 0):

I runs into the similar complains. It turns out that my external library has the same class as those in the android SDK.

So my resolution is that use customized SDK instead of android SDK.

To do that, following the following steps:
o    A, change the directory 'sdk.dir' in local.properties 
o    B, "sync project with SDK files". The button should be able to be located on toolbar. On the popup window, choose "project SDK". 
o    It may ask for downloading platform build tool (depends on definition in build.gradle file. For instance, in the filed of buildToolsVersion, the value is 23.0.3. Android studio may ask for the permission to download it. Allow the download. 
o    Android studio shall be able to compile and build APK.​