# trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class": Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I added the Dom4j maven repository and always get this build error.

***trouble processing “javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class”: Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)***

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.de.wearabletest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'
}
```

I have not found a solution elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted to fix androids "ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class" went bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266853/attempted-to-fix-androids-ill-advised-or-mistaken-usage-of-a-core-class-went-b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It seems that some classes used in Dom4j in maven repository are not supported in android.**

> I found a a lib  **dom4j-android** on google.code https://code.google.com/p/dom4j-android/
>   But after using the **dom4j-android** lib I removed it again.
>
> The reason is that every xpath
>   expression threw an error even if it cleary correct expression. So i can advise against using this lib.
>
> The **javax.xml.xpath.XPath** clasess I use now and they works great for xpath expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Decoy's ponit, I fixed the problem and searched out an available dependency in maven center.

in your module's bulid.gradle

try use

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  //compile 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'
  compile 'dom4j:dom4j:20040902.021138'
}
```

Comment: It works for me after changing from `dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1` to `dom4j:dom4j:20040902.021138`.