# Problems with twilio java library into android project with build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, twilio

I am facing few problems including the [twilio library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/7.4.0) into an android project.
First I included with

```
 compile group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '7.4.0'
```

But I started getting this ill-advised or mistaken problem as mentioned int this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266853/attempted-to-fix-androids-ill-advised-or-mistaken-usage-of-a-core-class-went-b)

So, I excluded the javax library with

```
compile (group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '7.4.0'){
    exclude group: 'javax.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-api'
}
```

But then I am getting run time errors complaining that twilio can't make HTTP call because it can't find the NetworkHttpClient

`com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:33)`

The dependency chain for twilio library looks like this. 
[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this? All I want to do this make a couple of HTTP calls to twilio to make a telephone call in my test and I can very well do this with a simple curl statement, so alternative approaches are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Java library is not meant to be used with Android, and as you've seen, when you try to use it, you will end up with networks errors since the library uses a version of Apache HTTP that is not supported by Android.

Now, back to what you're trying to do, I suggest that instead of trying to make requests to the Twilio API from Android directly, you add a backend server, that way, you just need to make a request to that backend server from your app. This stops your credentials being visible to anyone who downloads your app.

I described how to send SMS from Android in [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html), but you should be able to modify it so you can also make telephone calls.

Then on your app you can do something like:

```
Call post(String url, Callback callback) throws IOException{
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("To", mTo.getText().toString())
            .add("Body", mBody.getText().toString())
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
```

If what you're trying to do however is make Voip calls, then you should look at the [Twilio Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk). The page has examples of how to use it.

Hope this helps you!